# yaz4j Url parameters for connection to library

Tags: java

> I get excamples from
>   https://github.com/indexdata/yaz4j/tree/master/examples/zgate  for get
>   library data. In excample have help text in commentary:
>
> **/* For dinosaur search use: ?zurl=z3950.loc.gov:7090/voyager&query=@attr 1=7
>   0253333490&syntax=usmarc*/**
>
> And i use this for url and get data from library.This url is dvided
>   into 3 pars: **1)zurl=z3950.loc.gov:7090/voyager 2)query=@attr 1=7
>   0253333490 3)syntax=usmarc**    ; I dont know how i can get this
>   parameters for  send. In this code used
>   **zurl=z3950.loc.gov:7090/voyager**  or **query=@attr 1=7 0253333490** or **syntax=usmarc**. How i must define how must be query format, or syntax
>   format or zurl format for sendind. Where i can for excample
>   z3950.loc.gov:7090/voyager, how i can know its format. And @attr 1=7
>   0253333490 its stange query format and etc.Please help for geting this
>   format.  And this is  my  servlet code code which gets this
>   parameters.

```
package web;/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995-2010, Index Data
 * All rights reserved.
 * See the file LICENSE for details.
 */

import org.yaz4j.Connection;
import org.yaz4j.Record;
import org.yaz4j.ResultSet;
import org.yaz4j.exception.ZoomException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;


/**
 *
 * @author jakub
 */
public class ZgateServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void init() throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("Zeta: java.library.path=" + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
    System.out.println("Zeta: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" + System.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"));
  }

  @Override
  /*
   * For dinosaur search use: ?zurl=z3950.loc.gov:7090/voyager&query=@attr 1=7 0253333490&syntax=usmarc
   *
   */
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    String zurl = request.getParameter("zurl");
    if (zurl == null || zurl.isEmpty()) { response.sendError(400, "Missing parameter 'zurl'"); return; }

    String query = request.getParameter("query");
    if (query == null || query.isEmpty()) { response.sendError(400, "Missing parameter 'query'"); return; }

    String syntax = request.getParameter("syntax");
    if (syntax == null || syntax.isEmpty()) { response.sendError(400, "Missing parameter 'syntax'"); return; }

    int maxrecs=10;
    if (request.getParameter("maxrecs") != null && !request.getParameter("maxrecs").isEmpty()) {
      try {
        maxrecs = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("maxrecs"));
      } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        response.sendError(400, "Malformed parameter 'maxrecs'");
        return;
      }
    }

    response.getWriter().println("SEARCH PARAMETERS");
    response.getWriter().println("zurl: " + zurl);
    response.getWriter().println("query: " + query);
    response.getWriter().println("syntax: " + syntax);
    response.getWriter().println("maxrecs: " + maxrecs);
    response.getWriter().println();

    Connection con = new Connection(zurl, 0);
    con.setSyntax(syntax);
    try {
      con.connect();
      ResultSet set = con.search(query, Connection.QueryType.PrefixQuery);
      response.getWriter().println("Showing " + maxrecs + " of " +set.getHitCount());
      response.getWriter().println();
      for(int i=0; i<set.getHitCount() && i<maxrecs; i++) {
        Record rec = set.getRecord(i);
        if (rec == null) continue;
        response.getWriter().print(rec.render());
      }
    } catch (ZoomException ze) {
      throw new ServletException(ze);
    } finally {
      con.close();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  }

  @Override
  public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Zeta search engine servlet";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, state your question more precisely. What problem are you facing?

Comment: I want get data from other libraries and other books, for that i must use different request params. For excamle in this code i used query=@attr 1=7 0253333490. And i dont know how to define request parameters format.

Comment: yaz4j.jar is ready java lib for getting data from all libraries based on my reguest paramers formats. And dont know from where to find this list of formats. I read yaz documentation i dont get understutable information there.

Comment: And here is documentation which read is  http://www.indexdata.com/yaz/doc/ and cant find infmation for my problem.